# Почему изменение имени переменной меняет поведение скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Я только начал учить js и уже чувствую себя как девочка из мема. Имя test в localStarage я не задавал. Почему в первом случае localStorage.getItem("test") это "null" а во втором, судя по всему, null?

```
var name = localStorage.getItem("test");
console. log(name + ' ' + typeof(name)); // null string
var foo = localStorage.getItem("test");
console. log(foo + ' ' + typeof(foo)); // null object
```

Comment: Это точно вся программа?

Comment: @EzioMercer да. Попробуйте запустить в консоль. В скриптах JS не получается такое.

Comment: Предполагаю, что это происходит из-за того, что в глобальной пространстве уже существует переменная `name` по умолчанию которая равна `void`. Пока не понял почему это [работает в консоли](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5VsL.png), но [не работает, к примеру в модулях](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d05Mm.png).

Comment: @eccs0103 переменная не может быть `void` - такого типа нет

Comment: @Grundy Я понимаю что это всего лишь комментарии JSDoc, но все же тогда [что это значит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDs5h.png)?

Comment: @eccs0103 In both NodeJS CommonJS modules and native ECMAScript modules, top-level variable declarations are scoped to the module, and are not added as properties to the global object. [Ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Comment: @eccs0103, это что угодно может значить, но никак не относится к js, в котором `void` - нет

Comment: @Grundy В каком плане нет?) Как тип имеешь ввиду?

Comment: @EzioMercer, да, выше речь шла про тип.

Answer (score 1):

Всё дело в том как работают 2 вещи:

1. `var` в глобальной области видимости
2. Свойство `name` у объекта `window`

И так по порядку:

1. Когда мы объявляем какую-то переменную с помощью `var` в глобальной области видимости, оно попадает в объект `globalThis`, что в браузере является `window`
2. Когда мы что-то записываем в `window.name`, то он [автоматически вызывает у этого значения `toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name#sect1)

Вот и получается, что мы получаем на выходе `name` - строка `"null"`